# How to view Solidity Require Function Messages from the front end?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I have a ReactJS project that can communicate with my smart contract.  However, in my smart contract I have used the Require function to check for certain conditions before proceeding to execute down stream code.  However, I do not know how to access the error messages in the event that certain conditions are not met.

For example:

```
 bool public isRed = false;
 require(isRed, "The state is not red");
```

How would I be able to access the "The state is not red" from the front end I am currently using Alchemy web3 to communicate with the blockchain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly use revert reason in web3.js to show meaningful error message in UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878031/how-to-properly-use-revert-reason-in-web3-js-to-show-meaningful-error-message-in)

Comment: I know in ethers.js, do you think it is useful to you?!